# Clarification regarding condition of semidirect product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, semidirect-product, combinatorial-group-theory

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Examples) says:

> More generally, a semidirect product of any two cyclic groups $C_m$ with generator $a$ and $C_n$ with generator $b$ is given by one extra relation, $aba^{−1} = b^k$, **with $k$ and $n$ coprime**; that is, the presentation:
>
> $$\langle a, b| a^m = e, b^n = e, aba^{-1} = b^k\rangle$$

Why must $k$ and $n$ be co-prime in this context?

Comment: In order to define a semidirect product, the  map $b \mapsto b^k$ must induce an automorphism of the cyclic group $\langle b \rangle$. That is the case if and only if $b^k$ has order $n$ (i.e. if it generates the group), which is true if and only if $k$ and $n$ are coprime.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes or down vote. Surely people are allowed to simply *wonder* things?!? (That is, this kind of question shows that the OP is trying to understand something, genuinely trying. So let's be encouraging folks!)